# Parallelizing many nested for loops in openMP c++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, nested-loops

Hi i am new to c++ and i made a code which runs but it is slow because of many nested for loops i want to speed it up by openmp anyone who can guide me. i tried to use '**#pragma omp parallel**' before **ip** loop and inside this loop i used '**#pragma omp parallel for**'  before **it** loop but it does not works

```
    #pragma omp parallel
    for(int ip=0; ip !=nparticle; ip++){
        inf14>>r>>xp>>yp>>zp;
        zp/=sqrt(gamma2);
        counter++;
        double para[7]={0,0,Vz,x0-xp,y0-yp,z0-zp,0};
        if(ip>=0 && ip<=43){
             #pragma omp parallel for
             for(int it=0;it<NT;it++){  
             para[6]=PosT[it];
                for(int ix=0;ix<NumX;ix++){
                    para[3]=PosX[ix]-xp;
                    for(int iy=0;iy<NumY;iy++){
                        para[4]=PosY[iy]-yp;
                        for(int iz=0;iz<NumZ;iz++){
                            para[5]=PosZ[iz]-zp;
                            int position=it*NumX*NumY*NumZ+ix*NumY*NumZ+iy*NumZ+iz;
                            rotation(para,&Field[3*position]);
                            MagX[position] +=chg*Field[3*position];
                            MagY[position] +=chg*Field[3*position+1];
                            MagZ[position] +=chg*Field[3*position+2];
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }enter code here
```

and my rotation function also has infinite integration for loop as given below

```
for(int i=1;;i++){
    gsl_integration_qag(&F, 10*i, 10*i+10, 1.0e-8, 1.0e-8, 100, 2, w, &temp, &error);
    result+=temp;
    if(abs(temp/result)<ACCURACY){
        break;
    }
}
```

i am using gsl libraries as well. so how to speed up this process or how to make openmp?

Comment: Before starting to parallelize your code, first make sure there are no inter dependencies. E.g. I don't see how you could run the for loop in parallel when one of the first statements is `para[6]=PosT[it];`. When you prepared your code for parallelized computing, make sure to use `__restrict__` for function arguments, e.g. in case MagX, MagY, MagZ and Field are arguments and never overlap. (Or `__restrict` depending on the compiler you use)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have inter-loop dependences, you can use the `collapse` keyword to parallelize multiple loops altoghether. Example:

```
void scale( int N, int M, float A[N][M], float B[N][M], float alpha ) {
  #pragma omp for collapse(2)
  for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < M; j++ ) {
      A[i][j] = alpha * B[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

I suggest you to check out the [OpenMP C/C++ cheat sheet (PDF)](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-4.5-1115-CPP-web.pdf), which contain all the specifications for loop parallelization.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set parallel pragmas inside another parallel pragma. You might overhead the machine creating more threads than it can handle. I would establish the parallelization in the outter loop (if it is big enough):

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int ip=0; ip !=nparticle; ip++)
```

Also make sure you do not have any [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) between threads (e.g. RAW).

Advice: if you do not get a great speed-up, a good practice is iterating by chunks and not only by one increment. For instance:

```
int num_threads = 1;
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp single
    {
        num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
    }
}
int chunkSize = 20; //Define your own chunk here
for (int position = 0; position < total; position+=(chunkSize*num_threads)) {
    int endOfChunk = position + (chunkSize*num_threads);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int ip = position; ip < endOfChunk ; ip += chunkSize) {
        //Code
    }
}
```

Comment: The default schedule policy for `omp for` is `static`, which already partitions the iteration space in contiguous chunks which is then distributed among the threads. I wouldn't say doing this manually is a good practice since the effect is more complex code for no real benefit.