# How to use parallelise two independent for loops in openmp?

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following loop setting:

```
for( int k = 0 ; k < N ; j++ )
{
    while( 1 )
    {
        for( int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
        {
            int sum = 0;

            for( int j = nums[i] ; j < nums[i+1] ; j++ )
            {
                sum = sum + nums[i];
            }

         }

         if( sum == some_desired_value )
               break;
     }
 }
```

I want to parallelise this code using openmp.
N is a very large integer. Since the outer k loop is very much independent of what is happening in the i loop, I planned on using parallel for in k and j loops as below. But I know that this is not a correct setting, as already the number of iterations will be distributed per thread in the k loop, and hence, only one thread will be there per k loop iteration, leaving no thread-iteration distribution possible for the inner i loop.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for( int k = 0 ; k < N ; j++ )
{
    while( 1 )
    {
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for( int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
        {
            int sum = 0;

            for( int j = nums[i] ; j < nums[i+1] ; j++ )
            {
                sum = sum + nums[i];
            }

         }

         if( sum == some_desired_value )
               break;
     }

     
 }
```

I want to know if there is some way possible where I can achieve the above setting?

PS: Nested loops might come handy, but I am not sure if I can use them in this setting?

Comment: Your example is incomplete. I guess you can use `if (nums[i] < nums[i + 1]) sum = nums[i] * (nums[i+1] - nums[i]);` instead of the inner for loop. Anyway, the inner for loop is hard to  parallelize, since the each calculation needs exclusive access to `sum`. In similar code, it's best to have a sum array where every individual iteration stores its value so these can run in parallel, then afterwards combine all results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parallelizing many nested for loops in openMP c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872940/parallelizing-many-nested-for-loops-in-openmp-c)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

Yes, I purposely omitted some code because it was not very much relevant to my problem. No, I could not omit the inner loop by if (nums[i] < nums[i + 1]) sum = nums[i] * (nums[i+1] - nums[i]);, here it seems it could be omitted, but my actual code is doing some more calculations which makes the loop necessary.

Well, the link question solves the issue by collapse, but I am not sure if collapse will be possible in my case, right?

Comment: your first line `for( int k = 0 ; k < N ; j++ )` makes no sense. Variable `k` is not used in the code, but `j` is increased. You mistyped something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as N is much bigger than the number of physical cpu cores at your disposal, you should not parallelize the inner loop as well. In parallel lingo one would say that the outer loop provides enough parallelism, such that trying to parallelize the inner loop will in the best case add more overhead due to thread creation and in the worst case oversubscribe you system.

Only if regularly N is of the same order of magnitude as the numbber of cores you should start to think about further parallelizing that loop nest, which in this case may be far from trivial.